# How to code this in angularjs

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I am having this code for a navbar active component in jquery, but I don't know how to make it in angularjs.

```
$(document).on("click", 'ul li', function(){
  $('ul li').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

Comment: We aren't a 'write this code for me' website; please tell us what you've already tried (i.e, edit your question to show the AngularJS code that you've tried).

Comment: function myCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.myClass = [];
    $scope.addClass = function() {
      $scope.myClass.push('red');
    }
    $scope.removeClass = function() {
      $scope.myClass.pop('red');
    }
    $scope.checkClass = function() {
      if($scope.myClass.indexOf('red') == -1) {
         alert('false');
      } else {
         alert('true');
      }
    }
}     but it not working

Comment: Yes.. now add that to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Applying a class can be done using `ng-class`, and assuming you have your Angular page/route setup already you can use `ng-click` to simply toggle the `active` value like below. You could also move this `ng-click` to any other HTML element if you wanted to.

```
<ul>
    <li ng-class="{'active': active}" ng-click="active = !active">Hello</li>
</ul>
```